# Python: How to get the URL to a file when the file is received from a pipe?

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, url, pipe

I created, in Python, an executable whose input is the URL to a file and whose output is the file, e.g.,

```
file:///C:/example/folder/test.txt --> url2file --> the file
```

Actually, the URL is stored in a file (url.txt) and I run it from a DOS command line using a pipe:

```
type url.txt | url2file
```

That works great.

I want to create, in Python, an executable whose input is a file and whose output is the URL to the file, e.g.,

```
a file --> file2url --> URL
```

Again, I am using DOS and connecting executables via pipes:

```
type url.txt | url2file | file2url
```

Question: `file2url` is receiving a file. How do I get the file's URL (or path)?

Comment: Do you mean that given only the basename `'test.txt'`, you want to find the full path `r'C:\example\folder\test.txt'`? What is the context for the problem? See [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/137096)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you probably can't.

If the url is not stored in the file, I seems very difficult to get the url. Imagine someone reads a text to you. Without further information you have no way to know what book it comes from.

However there are certain usecases where you can do it.

### Pipe the url together with the file.

If you need the url and you can do that, try to keep the url together with the file. Make url2file pipe your url first and then the file.

### Restructure your pipeline

Maybe you don't need to find the url for the file, if you restructure your pipeline.

### Index your files

If only a certain files could potentially be piped into file2url, you could precalculate a hash for all files and store it in your program together with the url. In python you would do this using a `dict` where the key is the file (as a string) and the value is the url. You could use `pickle` to write the dict object to a file and load it at the start of your program.

Then you could simply lookup the url from this dict.

You might want to research how databases or search functions in explorers handle indexing or alternative solutions.

### Searching for the file

You could use one significant line of the file and use something like `grep` or `head` on linux to search **all** files of your computer for this line. Note that `grep` and `head` are programs, not python functions. For DOS, you might need to google the equivalent programs.

FYI: `grep` searches for one line of text inside a file.
`head` puts out the first few lines of a file. I suggest comparing only the first few lines of files  to avoid searching through huge file.

Searching all files on the computer might take very long.

You could only search files with the same size as your piped input.

### Use url.txt

If file2url knows the location of the file `url.txt`, then you could look up all files in url.txt until you find a file identical to the file that was piped into your program. You could combine this with the hashing/ indexing solution.

Answer (score 1):

'file2url' receives the data via standard input (like keyboard).
The data is transferred by the kernel and it doesn't necessarily have to have any file-system representation. So if there's no file there's no URL or path to that for you to get.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to do it by obvious way:

```
$ cat test.py | python test.py 
import sys
print ''.join(sys.stdin.readlines())
print sys.stdin.name

<stdin>
```

So, filename is "< stdin>" because, for the python there is no filename - only input.

Another way is a system-dependent. Find a command line, which was used, for example, but no garantee that is will be works.